# In TCL/TK Remove binding after widget destruction

Tags: binding, widget, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a canvas located in a Sub window of my main application:

```
.dsm.nb.mdlbuild.canvas
```

additionally I have the following (one of several) proc helping me letting the user move stuff around on the canvas:

```
proc grab { xx yy } {

    global currentx currenty
    set currentx $xx
    set currenty $yy
}
```

I use this binding:

```
.dsm.nb.mdlbuild.canvas bind $tagtomove  <Button-1>      {grab  %x %y }
```

PROBLEM:

When the user closes the window (.dsm) the canvas gets distroyed to, but the binding seems to 'survive'.

When the user then subsequentually clicks somwhere he gets the error:

```
wrong args: should be "grab xx yy"
```

This because xx and yy is empty i suppose because the canvas is gone together with the parrent window...

I have tried to set the binding to nothing after the .dsm window is destroyed:

```
.dsm.nb.mdlbuild.canvas bind $tagtomove  <Button-1>      { }
```

and to use the "break" command, but with no success.

```
.dsm.nb.mdlbuild.canvas bind $tagtomove  <Button-1>      break
```

How can i remove the binding uppon closing the window (.dsm)  in which the canvas is located so that this error does dissapear?

Comment: Bindings are automatically removed when their widget is deleted (except in some cases which don't apply here). But don't override standard commands unless you are aware of exactly what they do, as a lot of code assumes you never do that. I remember creating an icon (photo image) for a toolbar button in my first GUI and calling it after the button action; the `open` icon got renamed shortly after that when *lots* of stuff broke weirdly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you used the name of a standard Tk command for your proc. The `grab` command is called from different places in the Tk library, but not always matching the number of arguments of your proc. This would cause the error. You can check this by dumping the value of $errorInfo after you received the error message.

So, just rename your proc to something other than `grab` (or any other built-in command).